# SQL Server 2008 option (recompile)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a parameterized query executed from an ASP.NET application, which is executed in SQL Server with the sp_executesql statement

```
e.g. 
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [COL1], [COL2]  FROM [MyView] 
WHERE (([COL1] = @PARM1) AND ([COL2] = @PARAM2 ) 
ORDER BY [COL3]',N'@PARAM1 int,@PARM2 int,@',@PARAM1=21,@PARM2=255
```

This query was running long (and timing out) in the production environment, but it was not in the testing environment.

The quick analysis determined the underlying tables needed correct indexes - and adding additional indexes in the production environment and partitioning the data resolved the performance issue in the production environment.

However, it wasn't clear as to why the testing environment never had this issue in the first place. After further investigation we determined:

1) All VM host/guest settings, server, OS settings we could find were the same, :

2) SQL Server 2008 versions were different. The testing environment (still) has the RTM Version (10.0.1600.22) and the production has SP2 (10.0.4064.0 )

3) When we added the OPTION(RECOMPILE) to the above SQL statement, the query performed correctly in all environments.

4) There were issues with the OPTION(RECOMPILE) in the RTM relase - there is some documentation/posts regarding this, but it is not clear to me as to explain this.

My question is:

At a technical level, why would the much older RTM version perform fine without the OPTION(RECOMPILE), but the newest version (SP2) was timing out?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It could a case of parameter sniffing: maybe, on your test server, a suitable execution plan was found and cached, and thus the query ran quickly. On the prod server, maybe a first run of the query picked an execution plan that wasn't optimal for subsequent executions...

Comment: I agree, that's what it looks like. Is there any tool/command that would give some stats on that?

Comment: You could flush the proc cache (`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`) and run your query again - if it's fast now, check out the execution plan - is it different from before?

Comment: thanks - that's what I thought. what I was hoping is there was some stats that would tell me 'why' ... but that does make sense

Answer (score 0):

Was there additional load on the production server (either within this database, or anywhere in the SQL server, or perhaps even a completely separate task on the server) that wasn't present in the test server?

Comment: hi ... none that we could see. The servers I had testing against were isolated - it really came down to ... add OPTION(RECOMPILE) .. and the query ran perfect every time; without that hint, older RTM version was slow.